# Form validation with smart wizard

Tags: jquery, html

I am using smart wizard  and on next button i need to check the filed not empty (required one) before loading next page.

**My Code:**

```
 $('.sw-btn-next').click( function() {

            $("#tbl_sales_form").validate();}
);
```

but im getting the error :
Uncaught TypeError: `$(...).validate is not a function`

Comment: could you plese add your code snipet

Comment: no i need entire code snipet including html

Answer (score 1):

I feel You're not loading the validation plugin.

Could you please paste your code here for more clarification.

Comment: i am not using 3rd party plugin , since i need to get the html5 validation similar when we press submit button

Comment: @roche `.validate()` is a third party library api

Comment: what i can do in this case with out using 3rd party api ?

Comment: Could you please post the code here I can have a look and suggest